# Magento 2 - How to get Base URL in cronjob

Tags: magento2, base-url, cronjobs

In other file I use this code to get base URL

```
$this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl()
```

where `$this->storeManager` is a instance of `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface`

My question is, how can I get **base URL** in **cronjob**? because the code gets store first before getting base url, and in cronjob, magento uses 0 as current store (Global store)

Any help would be appriciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think before calling `getBaseUrl()` you need to set your current store then you can get correct URL.

`$this->storeManager->setCurrentStore($storeId);`

Where `$storeId` is your store Id which you want the base URL.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks :)